# How to pass a Func here

Tags: c#, func

Let's say I have a class like follows.

```
public class Circle
{
    private double radius;
    public double GetArea(Func<double, double> operand)
    {
        return operand(radius);
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to pass the Func at runtime to do required calculation

Comment: Your class definition has no way of setting the `radius`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var area = circle.GetArea((r) => 2 * Math.PI * r * r);
```

Seems a bit silly, why not

```
public class Circle
{
    public Circle(double radius) { Radius = radius; }
    public double Radius { get; private set; }
    public double Area {
      get {
         return 2 * Math.PI * Radius * Radius;
      }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope the answer is self-explanatory:

```
Func<double, double> multiply = (r)=>r*r;

double area = GetArea(multiply, radius);

public double GetArea( Func<double, double> operand , double rad )
{
    return operand( rad );
}
```

Comment: how you pass the value of r when you call GetArea method?

Comment: Basically the scenario I have, this code is provided in part of a third party library that I cannot change. This means that I cannot make any change in GetArea method.

Comment: @pauldeter  GetArea function prototype does need value of r. You pass a delegate only.